# How to resample 5 minute interval data into hourly data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have following dataset

| Date | Time | Temperature_C | Wind speed_kmph | Precipitation Rate_mm | Pressure_hPa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:00:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0 | 1023.37 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:05:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0.51 | 1023.71 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:10:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0 | 1023.37 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:15:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0 | 1023.71 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:20:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0.25 | 1023.37 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:25:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0 | 1023.71 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:30:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0.51 | 1023.37 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:35:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0 | 1023.71 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:40:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0.25 | 1023.37 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:45:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0 | 1023.71 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:50:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0 | 1023.37 |
| 1/1/2017 | 23:55:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0 | 1023.71 |
| 1/2/2017 | 00:03:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0.51 | 1023.37 |
| 1/2/2017 | 00:08:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0 | 1023.71 |
| 1/2/2017 | 00:13:00 | 7.72 | 1.61 | 0 | 1023.37 |
| 1/2/2017 | 00:18:00 | 7.61 | 0 | 0.25 | 1023.71 |

As you can see, I have problem with time as they are NOT exactly regular. On 02/01/2017 00:00:00, there was problem with recorder and hence there was no data but as soon as the problem was fixed, the recorder started recording from 00:00:03 on the same day. Similarly, this is just small dataset from large one. The other problem is sometimes the dataset has more than 5 minutes of interval (say, the recorder recorded on 03/01/2017 00:05:00 and then the recorder recorded on 00:17:00 and sometimes the recorder is not fixed on the same day)
How can I effectively resample the data?

I have never worked on such data, so I don't even know what to begin with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an datetime index and use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
(df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%Y%H:%M:%S'))
   .drop(columns=['Date', 'Time'])
   .resample('H').mean()
)
```

*NB. using the mean here, but you can aggregate the way you want.*

Output:

```
                     Temperature_C  Wind speed_kmph  Precipitation Rate_mm  Pressure_hPa
2017-01-01 23:00:00          7.665            0.805               0.126667       1023.54
2017-01-02 00:00:00          7.665            0.805               0.190000       1023.54
```

Comment: If there is wind direction, how could you digitize it and get hourly data for it?